# postfix + procmail -- process serially, not in parallel

Tags: email, postfix, procmail, mail-transport-agent

Trying to design a system that can filter incoming email messages from a syslog server.  Need to drop if they appear to be duplicates (throttle them).  Procmail pipes them to a perl script for processing.  That's all working, except if I get a flurry of emails all at once, postfix seems to spawn multiple instances of the piped script.  Obviously this is desirable in most cases, but for this project, I have to be able to process the incoming messages one at a time so that a database field can be updated with a timestamp so that subsequent messages that match a criteria can be dropped instead of forwarded to the recipients. **Is there a way to "queue" these incoming messages to be processed one at a time, instead of in parallel?   Thanks.

Comment: Where do you want to do the queueing? You could set Postfix to only deliver one message at a time, or you could do a little magic in procmail. Which you'd choose depends on the results you are after. So, which will it be?

Comment: This is not high volume.  I think I'll look into the procmail lock file idea first.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use procmail's locking to make multiple instances execute one instance of the perl script at given time. See `man procmailrc` and `man procmailex`

```
:0 w: script.lock
| /.../script.pl
```

O course there are other ways **but** How many messages per hour do you expect to process in peak and average hour?

Comment: The last sentence of this answer really should have been a comment on the question. It does however not detract from the validity of the answer itself.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I see it as a hint to someone wishing another **solution**.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the solution by Andrzej, you can set a lock for a wider region than just a single recipe if you need to with the `LOCKFILE` special variable.

```
# Only one instance of Procmail can enter this region
LOCKFILE=.procmail-critical-region.lock

:0
* condition
| action

value=`program`

:0
* another condition
| another action

# We are done now; okay for another instance to enter
LOCKFILE=
```

In principle, you could have multiple critical sections which are guarded by the same lock file, though I am hard pressed to think of a scenario where this would actually be useful.